# Como abrir uma dll do .Net

Tags: c#

Cheguei na empresa e já peguei um programa em andamento e o desenvolvedor anterior saiu da empresa. O programa está bem feito. As execuções das `procedures` e tabelas estão dentro de uma `dll` e preciso ver o código lá escrito dentro dos métodos. No object Browser eu consigo visualizar os métodos, mas não consigo ver o que esta escrito. A pergunta é:

Há como abrir uma dll?

Apesar de ter os fontes não tenho esse.

Comment: Essa biblioteca e' interna (foi escrita pela empresa) ou externa?

Comment: Ela foi escrita pela empresa, é interna, é nossa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a biblioteca for interna (escrita pela empresa), então a empresa deve manter o código  fonte algures, provavelmente num repositorio DVCS/VCS diferente.
Nesse caso basta perguntar a um colega onde é mantido o código fonte.

Se a biblioteca for externa, só é possível ver o codigo fonte se o projecto for open-source, e nesse caso basta pesquisar pelo projecto.

Se a biblioteca for interna mas a empresa nao tem o codigo fonte (devido a um desastre técnico, perda de servidores, etc), entao diz ao teu superior que nao consegues progredir no projecto sem o codigo fonte dessa biblioteca, e ele irá ajudar-te como poder.

---

As bibliotecas (dlls) nao têm uma cópia do codigo fonte. Elas estão escritas numa linguagem diferente, IL (Intermediate Language), que está niveis abaixo de C# e niveis acima de machine language.

Existem alguns projectos que tentam converter IL em codigo C# (JetBrains dotPeek), mas o resultado nao é 100% fiel, e os comentarios originais do codigo sao perdidos. Estas ferramentas sao usadas maioritariamente para fins académicos (aprender o que se passa *behind the scenes*), quase nunca para fins profissionais, e certamente o teu patrão/manager nao te deve colocar numa posição em que precises de usar estas ferramentas para fazer o teu trabalho.

Comment: Esse código estava guardado em outro ambiente, só vou esperar a pessoa responsável voltar das férias para me autorizar a abrir e fazer as mudanças necessárias.